# Reloading Table and Clearing Cell Row Selection

Tags: uitableview, ios8, xcode6

Up to iOS 8 and Xcode 6, I was able to use a UITableViewController much like Apple's Settings to configure my applications.  In segue'ing from one table back to the calling table, I would reload the calling table to update data in the cells, re-select the calling row and then let the view appear animated to clear the selection.

Here's the code in the viewWillAppear method I've been using:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:lastselected animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
```

While the cell data is updated, the nice slow disappearance of the selected row/cell doesn't happen.  It is effectively cleared immediately.  I've tried just about everything I can think of and can't get this working.  Please help...

What has changed and how can I get that nice transition back?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`viewWillAppear` is called before your view is on the screen. So you'll not get any animations working correctly if fired from inside that method. Use `viewDidAppear` instead and you should see more reliable animations on transition.. Potentially use `performSelector` with a delay as well if you feel it's happening too quickly.

Personally as well, I'd call `[super viewDidAppear:animated];` first in this case. I can't see a reason why it'd be below the other lines of code.

Also just so I'm being 100% clear... `viewWillAppear` is obviously ok for reloading the tableView so lets do this...

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:lastSelected animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
}
```

Or with the perform selector delay on viewDidAppear...

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self performSelector:@selector(animateCellSelectionAtIndexPath:) withObject:lastSelected afterDelay:0.2f];
}

-(void)animateCellSelectionAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  That actually didn't help as you had planned, but I was able to get it working by doing this:

    -(void)viewWillAppear: (BOOL)animated
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:lastselected animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    [self performSelector:@selector(animateCellSelectionAtIndexPath:) withObject:lastselected afterDelay:0.05f];

}


-(void)animateCellSelectionAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

Comment: In your comment code, you're performing the `selectRowAtIndexPath` call twice. You shouldn't need the first `selectRowAtIndexPath` only the one in the perform selector with delay. I'd be very surprised if my viewDidAppear version doesn't work, though I'm happy the delay in this case worked out for you... as I say, you can't guarantee that though, as technically it's an indeterminate amount of time before it 'did appear'.

Comment: Good catch..it's actually a deselectRowAtIndexPath and not another select. Copy/Paste error.